# Check memory status before malloc and after free C

Tags: c, memory-management, dynamic, malloc, free

I want to know how much memory was used before executing a program, which uses `malloc()`,  and how much it is allocated after the program has finished his execution. I want to do this to check if my `free()` actually cleans up all the memory that I've allocated.

When I used to do concurrent programming in order to do this i used `ipcs` to know how many semaphores, queses and shared memory was allocated before and after the execution of the program.

Is there something similar to check our `malloc()` and `free()` efficiency?

I'm running ubuntu 16.04

Thanks a lot

Comment: for \*nix systems try valgrind, for windows there's drmemory.

Comment: "by hand" solution: run your main program in a loop and check if program memory is stable or if there are "leaks".

Comment: There is a built-in memory profiler in Visual Studio on Windows there is massif on non-Windows.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre "check if program memory is stable or if there are leaks" how can i do that?

Comment: on windows I use process manager.

Comment: Note that the o/s will free all the memory allocated to your program (process) when it terminates — except perhaps shared memory segments which can have a life independent of the process that created it, but they don't count because they're not allocated by `malloc()` anyway.  So, you have to do the checking while the process is running — that's where [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) comes in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

an extra point to answer, valgrid has a tool called

> massif

, which is a heap profiler. it can be used to analyse heap usage throughout the program. you can also see the heap usage graphically, with help of

> massif

and

> ms_print

command

more info and documentation can be found [here](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/ms-manual.html)

Answer (score 0):

I took @Felix Palmen comment as an valid answer; the Valgrind tool fits perfectly for my needs.  To install it:

```
sudo apt-get install libc6-dbg gdb valgrind
```

For the documentation, this is the official [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) web site.